# Contao 4.1.2 installation just does not work out

Tags: symfony, contao

I have extracted and copied the source files from https://contao.org/de/download.html (Contao 4.1.2 zip) to my web space (givoo.de) per FTP.

After visiting the url givoo.de/web/install.php it tells me to set the password and directly after that I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Patchwork\grapheme_strlen() in /kunden/484914_14059/webseiten/vendor/patchwork/utf8/src/Patchwork/Utf8.php on line 234
```

I mean, there is not much else to do. A composer or such is not needed with the newer versions beginning in 4.1 or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need at least PHP `5.4` to run Contao 4. If you do run PHP `5.4` or higher already, then your PHP environment does not have the [PHP intl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) extension enabled, which is currently required for Contao 4.

PHP intl is integrated into the PHP binary since PHP `5.4`, however some Linux distributions come with a custom built PHP binary without the intl extension.

Check with your hosting provider if and how you can enable the PHP intl extension for your server.

See also https://github.com/contao/check/issues/95

Comment: Great, Contao 4.12 installation went through now. Just one other question: I can login into the Contao backend now, but I cannot find the symphony app/manager/... Did I miss something? It just looks similar to this now: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Contao3-backend.PNG/300px-Contao3-backend.PNG